# start mms with image by using an intent, without having to go through intent chooser

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to start an mms message using the default text app on the phone. However when I use the code below, it works correctly but I am first brought to the intent chooser page with all the applications that I can choose to handle my intent. Is there a way to still use an intent the way I am currently, but without having to go through the intent chooser. I want it to immediately create the mms on the default texting app on the phone.

```
public void sendImage(View v)
{
    Intent mmsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/smile.png")));
    mmsIntent.setType("image/png");
    startActivity(mmsIntent);
}
```

Comment: Currently when I go to the intent choosing page it seems to shows almost all my apps, even apps like googlemaps which doesn't make much sense for an intent made to send an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing as following

```
Intent eventIntentMessage =getPackageManager()
 .getLaunchIntentForPackage(Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(getApplicationContext));
startActivity(eventIntentMessage);
```

It will work only on SDK_INT>=19

You can also try the following

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,     
Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/image_4.png"));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Preferably, I'd want something that also works on lower api levels, and I'm trying to send an image which is an mms so I don't think specifying an sms would work.